# Entity framework validation error on update with split tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table in SQL which contains one BLOB column. To avoid that this column is loaded into memory each time I want to access the other columns, I have done an EF table split. This way, I have two entities for the same table and the BLOB is only loaded lazily at the moment I want to access it. So to be clear: there should be a 1-to-1 relationship between those two entities.
However, when I'm updating the not-BLOB properties, I get the somewhat expected validation error that SoundFile is required and not present... But if I set it to be not required, EF is unable to share the tables...
Some code is shown below:

```
[Table("Files")]
public class File
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(300, MinimumLength = 0)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [Required]
    public virtual SoundFile SoundFile { get; set; }
}

[Table("Files")]
public class SoundFile
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("File")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("SoundFile")]
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }

    // Property is needed to tell EF that it's a one-to-one relationship
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Required]
    public virtual File File { get; set; }
}
```

There might be some mistake in there which is causing the problem, however, when I changed something (let's say related to the Required tags or so) it didn't work either because then EF was complaining I could not have them share a table... Anyway, when I try to update the file name and/or description like shown below, I get validation errors because the SoundFile property is null, as I want to avoid loading it from the database to do such a simple update. The variable `value` is the updated variable.

```
using (DataContext ctx = new DataContext())
{
    ctx.Files.Attach(value);
    var entry = ctx.Entry(value);
    entry.Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;
    entry.Property(x => x.Description).IsModified = true;

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any thoughts on this would be awesome! Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** When I try to delete a File record from the database, using the File entity class, again because I don't need the BLOB for that, I get the error that I'm missing a required attribute. However, making the property `SoundFile` not required breaks it, as EF then says: The entity types 'SoundFile' and 'File' cannot share table 'Files' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

**Edit 2:** As per request, here is the code of the DataContext class. It is basic, as I assumed that the relationships between entities were captured in the other classes.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("name=DataContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit 3:** The updating of values now works. I had to set `[Key, ForeignKey("SoundFile")]` and `[Key, ForeignKey("File")]` in File and SoundFile respectively on their ID properties. This way, I could remove the Required attribute on the SoundFile property in File and it would keep the 1-to-1 relation. However, when I try to delete a record in the database I still get: "Invalid data encountered. A required relationship is missing. Examine StateEntries to determine the source of the constraint violation." The StateEntries do not contain anything useful though... Debugger can't see what's in it. Code:

```
 using (DataContext ctx = new DataContext())
 {
     var file = ctx.Files.Find(id);
     ctx.Files.Remove(file);
     ctx.SaveChanges(); // Throws here
 }
```

Comment: I'm wondering how you have configured this relationship  in your DbContext (DbSet). wite your plz your DbContext i want to see it!

Comment: I have not, the relationship is configured entirely in these classes. The context just contains the DbSet<T> properties. Thought this was a cleaner approach.

Comment: contains both? DbSet<File> Files and DbSet<SoundFile> SoundFiles? this is not easy to materialized from EF because the table does not have the same type/class properties. and when you do Select() ? which type will be retrun for you? in the database is one type? are you using complex types?

Comment: In the database, the two entities are one table, indeed. This is also why the DataContext only contains DbSet<File>, as you can now see above, I changed the post.

Comment: You got the right idea, partially updating the file using `Attach` and `Entry`. I'm not sure why the `SoundFile` property is being validated, but you could try `ctx.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`. If that does not help, I'm curious to see what `value` actually is.

Comment: Removing the [Required] tag, and adding the correct ForeignKey attributes worked. Updating now works fine, however, deleting still gives me issues...